# Rails - ActiveRecord :has_many association is not being loaded when queried with :includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please have a look at this basic associations setup (Rails 4.2.1):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

With these models the next code works as expected and keeps the association `loaded`:

```
parent = Parent.first
parent.kids.to_a
parent.association(:kids).loaded? # => true
```

**But**: adding an `.includes(:school)` prevents the association being loaded/cached for some reason

```
parent = Parent.first
parent.kids.includes(:school).to_a
parent.association(:kids).loaded? # => false
```

Looking at SQL logs I see exact the same select query so I expect the association to be loaded/cached.

### The question

Why is this happening?

ActiveRecord preloads/caches `parent.kids` in the first example. I want to understand why its not possible in the second example with `includes` call?

An ideal answer for me would include references to the sources.

Thanks for any help

### P.S.

The workaround I'm using is setting `association.target` manually:

```
parent.association(:kids).target = parent.kids.includes(:school).to_a
```

Comment: Right. Because you’ve not added kids to the parent variable. You’ve assigned it to a new one as the root model. What are you trying to do? 1) list of kids + school for a version parent? Or 2) list of parents with their kids + schools?

Comment: @TomDunning what do you mean by "adding kids to the parent variable"? ActiveRecord preloads :kids in the first example. I want to understand why its not possible in the second example with "includes" call

Comment: You’ve done this `kids = new_stuff` rather than `parent = Parent.first.includes(kids: [:school])` which will then allow you to access kids and school info. The second example you gave you’ve created `kids =` which is kids at the root with schools attached, so kids is already loaded and you can’t check the assoc on `kids=` because kids is the root (so `kids.association(:kids).loaded?` is just nonsense.

Comment: As kind as you iterate through `kids` the second example you’re fine.

Comment: @TomDunning I'm afraid there's a misunderstanding. I've updated my code examples because `kids` variable could be confusing.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not looking for other ways to structure the code. I'm looking for explanation of this behaviour

Comment: Got you, thanks that helps a lot. Ok so, because you’ve not joined kids to parent using `includes`. You’ve instead made kids the Base table / model which you want to look at, rather than looking at the parent and including kids. Because kids is the base / main model it’s not associated at that point, because it can’t be associates to itself.

Comment: I think the "problem" is that `kids` is actually NOT loaded, what is loaded is `kids.includes(:school)`. The query may be the same because you aren't actually using that includes anywhere, but your are telling ActiveRecord to load somethings that IS NOT `kids` so it makes sense to not mark it as loaded.

Comment: So if you try `parent.joins(kids: [:schools]).to_a.association(:kids).loaded?` You should get true. And `parent.kids.joins(:school).association(:school).loaded?` should also be true. `parent.kids` forms a new query, rather than joining on the parents table, as it can just select on parent_id.

Comment: @arieljuod yep it sounds very similar to how I understand it. I'm thinking if there's an opportunity to make rails understand that its actually the same query as without `includes`. Thanks for your time guys, I will probably move this to a GH issue to continue investigation

Comment: @TomDunning thank you, I will think about this

Comment: Let me know if you’re happy and I’ll turn it into an answer

Comment: @nsave if you want the association to ALWAYS include that `includes` call maybe you can add an association scope so the association IS the one with `.includes` (`has_many :kids, -> { includes(:school) }`